# bootstrap switch selected option alert not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 with bootstrap Switch for checkbixes and radio buttons. I am trying to alert selected value(when switched) but no alert. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preAuth').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
        alert(data.value);
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class ="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Does payment profile exists ?</label>                                        
    <label class="checkbox-inline">                                         
        <input type="checkbox" id="preAuth" name="preAuth" data-on="primary" data-off="info" data-on-label="YES" data-off-label="NO" >
    </label>
</div>
```

Original documentation for [Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/)

If you see Toggle State sample, if you click on "State!" button, it is showing alert but am not able to understand how tha tis displaying the alert. I cannot find code that is calling an alert when clicked on button.

Comment: I can't see what you have edited Adrift.

Comment: I see your edits now. Thanks for adding html tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to create the switch first. You need this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#preAuth').bootstrapSwitch(); //create the switch
    //Now you can call it:
    $('#preAuth').on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
          alert(data.value);
    }); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBQVn/2/)

Comment: Still not working. Your fiddle example also not working.

Comment: @user3067524 My fiddle works perfectly: you click on the checkbox and it displays "true" or "false" depending on the state. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!. In your fiddle, onLoad is loding jQuery 2.0 and not working. I chnaged it to 1.9 and it worked. But in my actaul code, i am using 1.9 and same code is not working.

Comment: @user3067524 that's very strange, when I test my fiddle, it works on all the versions of jQuery 1.8.3 and above. I didn't test the other ones because they are too old anyway.

Comment: Iam using IE9, Is that causing the issue you think ?

Comment: @user3067524 I tested it with Chrome and works perfectly. I tested with IE10 and then it doesn't work if you use jquery 2.0.2. So yes, it seems that IE is the problem (not surprising...)

Comment: Ihave tested Fiffle again with 1.8 and 1.9 and working fine but not 2.0

Comment: Aha!..I found index.js in the switch website that is initializing inputs and button cliks defined. // state
  $('#toggle-state-switch-button').on('click', function () {
    $('#toggle-state-switch').bootstrapSwitch('toggleState');
  });

Comment: @user3067524 that's correct. That's why I know you need the `$('#preAuth').bootstrapSwitch()` call if you want it to work

Comment: Hi, I am using jquery 1.10.2 in my project and this sample is still not working. You can reproduce the issue using 1.10.1 in fiddle.

Comment: OMG, I found the issue finally. Wow!!. The code has to be the first call with in document ready function. I have some other functions in ready fucnction and i copied this test code after those functions and id not work. Finally, I have moved this code to the top of the rady function and started working. I wouldl ike to know what is hapening here if possible. Thank you for your halp though. I iwll accept the answer.

Comment: I am getting following error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` online  `$('#preAuth').bootstrapSwitch()`

Comment: anyone curious about a working example of that fiddle in this answer, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/rBQVn/9/